# Menu of some applications broken

Tags: themes, mate

Some of my apps have this "theme" problem, I think. It seems that some lines are missing.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I only switched to Mate desktop and got this:

[image]

Did anyone get this ?

Comment: Your question is kinda silly, in it's own sense. I could answer you with a simple "No never seen it before" and it would be a correct answer. What you actually want to ask is probably how to fix that...

Comment: Indeed @Ziazis, you're right, that would be a possible and correct answer.  And I never seen it before either.

Comment: As it happens I just did an 18.04 install and I have exactly the same problem in some applications.

Comment: The problem in my case was caused by using the wrong GTK theme. There are only very few themes in modern distro versions that actually work properly; in fact the "Adwaita" theme/style is the one that worked properly for me. I'm running xfce4 on 18.04 and other themes just do bizarre things.